# Periodic problem with kubernetes: An error: "The connection to the server x.x.x.:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?"

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Good afternoon!
Setting up my first k8s cluster :)
I set up a virtual machine on vmware, set up a control plane, connected a worker node, set up kubectl on the master node and on a laptop (vmware is installed on it). I observe the following problem: periodically, every 2 - 5 minutes, the api-server stops responding, when you run any kubectl command (for example, "kubectl get nodes"), an error appears: "The connection to the server 192.168.131.133:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?" A few minutes pass - everything is restored, in response to the "kubectl get nodes", the system shows the nodes. A few more minutes - again the same error. The error synchronously appears both on the master node and on the laptop.

This is what it looks like (for about 10 minutes):
[image: It doesn't seem like it should be]

At the same time, if you execute commands on the master node

```
$ sudo systemctl stop kubelet
$ sudo systemctl start kubelet
```

everything is immediately restored. And after a few minutes again the same error.

I would be grateful if you could help interpret these logs and tell me how to fix this problem?

kubectl logs at the time of the error (20:42:55):
[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXjVg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Could imagine that the process on 192.168.131.133 is restarting which is leading to a connection refused when it is not listening any more on the API port.

You should start investigating if you can see any hw issues.

Either CPU is increasing leading to a restart. Or memory leak.

You can check the running processes with.

```
ps -ef
```

Use

```
top
```

Command to see CPU consumption.

There should be some logs and events in k8s available as well.

It seems no connectivity issue as you are receiving a clear failure back.

Comment: thanks for the reply!

Found out that the error "The connection to the server xxx: 6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?" appears at the moment when the kube-apiserver process disappears from the list of processes.
Unfortunately, I was unable to view the kube-apiserver logs (ctljournalctl -u kube-apiserver gives "-- No entries --"; /var/log/kube-apiserver.log is missing). I would be grateful if you tell me where to look for the necessary logs!
The kubectl logs show some errors, but they don't seem to be related to my problem (see first post)

Comment: Yes makes sense. There is a CrashLoopBackoff for kube-apiserver in your log. There is probably something happening in the node before which leads to that behavior. Can you look at journalctl. What is happening before that?